# Python, loops and iteration

Tags: python

Define the method below to return the lowest factor of an arbitrary integer. The lowest factor is the smallest number greater than 1 that will divide evenly into the parameter(which will be 2 or higher).And this is my code, I don't know why is incorrect.

```
def first_factor(n):
    for num in range(2,n):
        if n % num == 0 and sqrt(n):
            return num
```

Comment: post the code here, not as a screenshot.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I don't know why is incorrect,could you help me thanks

Comment: @Xuan for your recently deleted question here is a start https://repl.it/EhJz/1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the square root of the number in the `range`, not as one of the conditions.

```
def first_factor(n):
    for num in range(2, int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n % num == 0:
            return num
```

Comment: Sorry this code is not correct, could you help me,thanks.

Comment: @Xuan - Not correct in what way? It works fine for me.

Comment: @Xuan - Without any description of what's incorrect about it (wrong result? error messages?), I can't possibly help.

Answer (score 1):

This is only the **definition** of the function - you have to **call it** and **print the result** to see it.
The full code may be:

```
def first_factor(n):
    for num in range(2, n + 1):
        if n % num == 0:
            return num

print(first_factor(3))
```

Note that I totally omitted square root as it is useless and it prevented to give a result for prime numbers.